# Amazon MWS sales summary

Tags: amazon-mws

I need to get the sales summary within a date range through Amazon MWS API. Ideally exactly the same sales data summary that a seller can see in their Seller Central gateway, shown in sales summary widget.

Comment: do you have any language preference such as php or python?

Comment: If you specify which language you would like, we would be able to give you a working example. The answer from @hpoe is right, but not written in a specific language.

Answer (score 1):

The whole API documentation for what you need to do can be found at this link http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html 
You will need to hit the orders listorders endpoint. The only endpoint specific required parameters are CreatedBefore and CreatedAfter. Which neatly fits with what you are asking.

According to Amazon's documentation this is an example of the request you'd need to make

```
GET https://mws.amazonservices.jp/Orders/2013-09-01
?AWSAccessKeyId=0PB842EXAMPLE7N4ZTR2
&Action=ListOrders
&MWSAuthToken=amzn.mws.4ea38b7b-f563-7709-4bae-87aeaEXAMPLE
&MarketplaceId.Id.1=A1VC38T7YXB528
&SellerId=A2NEXAMPLETF53
&Signature=ZQLpf8vEXAMPLE0iC265pf18n0%3D
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&LastUpdatedAfter=2013-08-01T18%3A12%3A21
&Timestamp=2013-09-05T18%3A12%3A21.687Z
 &Version=2013-09-01
```